# Order message table by "thread" or "discussion"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a chat, let's call "thread" a discussion by two users.
I need to order this:

```
        from_id |   to_id | message_text | send_time
----------------+---------+--------------+--------------------
             24 |      25 |some text     | 2016-02-27 18:48:26
             36 |      34 |some text     | 2016-03-02 16:40:03
             24 |       1 |some text     | 2016-03-10 17:02:56
             83 |      84 |some text     | 2016-03-16 11:58:27
             84 |      83 |some text     | 2016-02-27 18:48:26
             83 |      84 |some text     | 2016-03-16 12:02:57
             25 |      24 |some text     | 2016-02-27 18:48:26
             84 |      83 |some text     | 2016-03-16 12:03:30
```

to be like

```
        from_id |   to_id | message_text | send_time
----------------+---------+--------------+--------------------
             24 |      25 |some text     | 2016-02-27 18:48:26
             25 |      24 |some text     | 2016-02-27 18:48:26 
             24 |       1 |some text     | 2016-03-10 17:02:56
             83 |      84 |some text     | 2016-03-16 11:58:27
             84 |      83 |some text     | 2016-02-27 18:48:26
             83 |      84 |some text     | 2016-03-16 12:02:57
             84 |      83 |some text     | 2016-03-16 12:03:30
             36 |      34 |some text     | 2016-03-02 16:40:03
```

Rows have to be ordered aggregating threads and every thread by time

Comment: So you call the conversation between two users, e.g. 24 and 25, a thread. And even if the next entry between them were of 2018-10-20 you would still regard this as the same thread. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it a thread when the same two users communicate, no matter what date and time and how much time between. You can hence find threads by merely looking for same partners. A thread's key could be `least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id)`. Use their first communication time as a sort key. Then join with your table again to get your records in order.

```
select m.*
from
(
  select 
    least(from_id, to_id) as lesser_id, 
    greatest(from_id, to_id) as greater_id, 
    min(send_time) as sortkey
  from mytable
  group by least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id)
) thread
join mytable m on least(m.from_id, m.to_id) = thread.lesser_id
               and greatest(m.from_id, m.to_id) = thread.greater_id
order by thread.sort_key, thread.lesser_id, thread.greater_id, m.send_time;
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need but @Gordon hint is a lot faster, is it possible to have the same result with a variation of that one i.e. without subquery?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You want to sort by "the" thread date (I chose the thread's start date for this). So you must identify threads first and find their dates. You must combine this thread information with the single entries then in order to sort these. As far as I am aware MySQL offers nothing to speed this up (like functional indexes or analytic functions). Sorry. Gordon's query sorts by thread partners instead, which is much simpler, but quite a different order.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply want to order these values by the pairs of the from and to ids:

```
select t.*
from t
order by least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id), send_time;
```

Comment: I like you answer because it's fast. It just misses that discussions started first should come first

Comment: Yes you are right, it came to my mind later that there was this element to clarify, sorry